# Applying tint() on a BufferedImage in processing

Tags: processing

I'm grabbing visual screen contents with the Robot Class which I'm then trying to set to half transparency. I'm following the reference for the tint command like so:

```
screenshot = robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(0,42,scrdim.width,36));
shot = new PImage(screenshot);
shot.resize(32,1);
tint(255,127);
image(shot,5,5,64-5,4);
```

But as soon as I use the tint command the image disappears completely, regardless of the actual aplha parameter value. Is it, because it because I'm dealing with a BufferedImage? I've been trying to figure out how to set the alpha of that directly, but with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your transparenvcy currently is 100%.
The syntax for tint is:

tint(color, transparency);

Simply invert your tint color for 50% transparency:

```
tint(255, 127);
```

Comment: Good spot, I corrected that in the question. I must have messed that up when experimenting before postin. But it sadly wasn't what causes the image to disappear. Still the same effect.

Comment: I'm just wondering, does it work when you use a different PImage, not converted from the robot class? --> The resize seems very harsh 32 : 1 ratio.

Comment: I know this isn't a good answer, but you can also get the screen without using Robot: http://forum.processing.org/one/topic/get-screencapture.html  After that just edit out the parts you want. And if you want to only capture the window of processing, processing has an inbuilt function for that: https://www.processing.org/reference/save_.html

Comment: Actually, that **is** a good answer. I didn't know Processing had a screen capture class. tint() works perfectly fine on the PImages that it returns, and the performance seems fine as well. Thanks! - To clarify what I'm doing: an Ambilight clone with a Fadecandy. I use the scaling to get more screen pixels per LED 'pixel' to reduce distortion. But I'd still like to take into account more screen area, that why I'm trying to overlay multiple screenshots.